# Where can I find the TMS Web Core Demos Source Code?

Tags: delphi, tms, tms-web-core

When you install TMS Web Core into your Delphi IDE, they give you an option of whether you want to install the Demos Source Code or not.

I ticked to install the Demos and open the folder after the installation, but now I can't remember where the Demos were located.

Where can I find the Demos? Where does TMS install them?

Comment: A folder shortcut should've been added to your Start menu.  On my computer, it's under TMS WEB Core RS XE14 > TMS WEB Core Demos, which points to C:\Users\youusername\AppData\Local\tmssoftware\registered\TMS WEB Core RSXE14\Demos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find most of your TMS installs under your local `AppData` folder within a `tmssoftware` folder:

```
C:\Users\[YourAccount]\AppData\Local\tmssoftware
```

`[YourAccount]` is your actual Windows account name. On my PC, my account name is `Admin`. So my path would be:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\tmssoftware
```

---

Once you're in the `tmssoftware` folder, then it just depends on whether you're using the trial or registered version. Also what version of TMS Web Core you're using.

I have the trial version installed for Delphi 11 Alexandria. So my full path to the [Demos](https://tmssoftware.com/site/tmswebcoredemos.asp) is:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\tmssoftware\trial\TMS WEB Core RSXE14\Demos
```

If I were to have a registered version, then it would be:

```
C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\tmssoftware\registered\TMS WEB Core RSXE14\Demos
```

---

A shortcut to it is also added to your Windows Start Menu:

[image: TMS Web Core folder shortcut in the Start Menu]

Comment: Really? Just enter [`%LOCALAPPDATA%`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/knownfolderid#FOLDERID_LocalAppData) as path into Explorer/Command Prompt.